Reliably checking if a thread can be created
EDIT: Having figured it out (see my own answer), I get that the question text below is misleading, which caused a lot of misunderstanding. I still believe it might help somebody who has the same issue.
Justification
I am asking this question (at least in its essence) now the third time, since the first and second attempt drifted off into discussions about details I did not intend.
I am nonetheless convinced that an answer to the actual core question would be a valuable contribution to people (like myself) who are not experts in multi-thread programming, since it is currently not easily found on the internet and poses a valid problem.
Question
Say we have a function fct to be run in parallel using threads. Now, it is OS-dependent if a thread can be spawned at a given moment, depending on the available RAM and other things. If it's not possible, and we still naively try to do so, the program will crash. So, how can we reliably decide if a thread can be spawned, and otherwise decide against it, such that the program doesn't crash uncontrollably?
(As others pointed out, the possible number of concurrently running threads is "usually" "very high". I have two different Windows machines, though, one with 48GB of RAM (Windows 10; VS 2019), the other with 64GB of RAM (Windows 11; VS 2022) for both of which this number is somewhere around <20 for the below (extremely simple!) example. For the actual, more complex code I try to improve, I am stuck with only 5 threads. The point is not to improve this number or find out why my machines are shitty. I rather want my code to run crash-free on any OS it encounters.)
To have a ground truth, consider this MWE:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

constexpr int NUM_JOBS{ 100 };   // Number of jobs to run.
constexpr int NUM_THREADS{ 15 }; // Number of threads run at most in parallel. Setting this to 20 crashes on my machine.

void fct(const std::string& str) // Some function to run in parallel.
{
   std::cout << "Processing job: " + str + "\n";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::vector<std::string> job_descriptions{}; // Different "configs" to call fct.
   std::vector<std::thread> threads{};
   int numThreads{ 0 };

   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_JOBS; i++) { // Create some "configs".
      job_descriptions.push_back("J" + std::to_string(i));
   }
 
   for (const auto& job : job_descriptions) { // Run the jobs, in parallel if possible.
      bool spawned{ false };

      while (!spawned) {
         if (numThreads < NUM_THREADS) { // Spawn new threads only if not more than NUM_THREADS are running simultaneously.
            threads.emplace_back(std::thread(fct, job));
            spawned = true;
            numThreads++;
         }
         else if (!threads.empty()) { // Otherwise wait for the topmost thread to finish before spawning new ones.
            threads.front().join();
            threads.erase(threads.begin());
            numThreads--;
         }
      }
   }

   for (auto& t : threads) t.join(); // Join the remaining threads in the end.

   return 0;
}

The function fct to run in parallel is very simple, it only prints one line to cout. Using some constant NUM_THREADS, we can control how many jobs are run in parallel at most. Setting this number too high yields on my Windows machines:
Exception thrown at 0x768BA892 in ***.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::system_error at memory location 0x06DCFA68.

(On Linux, I can set it very high, but that's, as said, not the point.)
The question is basically, can we replace the condition numThreads < NUM_THREADS with something to the effect of: "If thread can be spawned"?

Even if there was an API for checking if a thread can be spwaned (and I don't think there is), it's a bit like the issue of Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong - even if you get a positive response it does not guarantee that a milisecond later when you actually create a thread it will succeed (because the state of the OS might have changed).

Catch the exception and set a flag that your full?  That said the number of threads in flight on a machine changes at run time so you never really know if you're at the cap or not.  I would suggest looking into why you are getting an exception in windows.

Can you add debug info, you say an exception is thrown but you fail to tell us on which line of code that happens. Side note, 15 threads should not be a problem on windows. (use debugger's break on exception feature to figure that out)

How exactly would such a function work? Imagine the following scenario:
Your program calls the hypothetical system function CanThreadBeCreated() and returns true. Exactly in the moment this function returns (i.e. your program has saved the result into a variable), you pause your program and let another program run. This program runs a single thread.
Now you let your program continue - the variable result is potentially out of date.

at 0x768BA892, at memory location 0x06DCFA68> It looks very strange. Having 48GB and 64GB PCs you run 32-bit applications.

Re, "The point is...I rather want my code to run crash-free." So, what prevents you from writing code that survives a failed attempt to create one more thread?

"It is difficult to make predictions, especially about the future." Instead, create the thread and catch the exception, If the exception occurs, then you know that you hit a limit somewhere, so you can try something else. (E.g. give the work to an existing thread, or just do the work from the main thread.)

Do you have real need of more and more threads or you imagine something theoretically and want to discuss it? I did not understood about "somewhere around <20" threads on Win10/11 - you expect that most programs need 30-40+ threads to work?

The code you shared doesn't seem to create more than NUM_THREADS threads at once. But if your real code creates NUM_THREADS threads per each job, it would explain the failure when NUM_THREADS==20. AFAIK, default stack size in Windows is 1 Mb, so it would require about 2 Gb of address space. This is the limit for 32-bit process.

In order to be able to hypothesize about a possible method for detecting whether a future thread creation would succeed, we would need to know why it sometimes fails for you, so we would need a demo that fails for everybody (on Windows) in the same way it does for you.

@500-InternalServerError, Isn't my example this demo? If not, why not?

I tried the try/catch thing, but it didn't work. Can anyone show me how it's done? I get all this about not being able to predict if a thread can be created, but HOW can I actually catch this error? I just can't do it - and I tried many things!

@Duke: Your code doesn't fail for me here.

@500-InternalServerError not for ANY NUM_THREADS / NUM_JOBS?

I don't know, I just tried it with 400 jobs and 200 threads - no error. What values would you suggest?

Are you on Windows? Because on Linux it's a zillion for me too.

@500-InternalServerError, would you mind taking this to a chat? I'm really unable to get this running...

As other people pointed, there is no value in having function that returns if a thread can be created. Regarding the OS limits, you can read this [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads][https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/ba-p/723824]

Thanks to all, particularly @3CxEZiVlQ! I figured it out and answered my own question - I'm sorry that there was so much misunderstanding in the past... But honestly, I did not expect THIS to be the problem...

If you are asking this, your code has bugs.

This is a great example of an XY problem.  FWIW, your code runs without error on my Windows machine for 30000 threads, which seems well above what would be needed.  So I guess I'm going to downvote because your crash is not reproducible for me.

@MichaelChourdakis, no it has not! See my own answer - which will surprise you... Or at least it surprised me ;-)

@Wyck: Please read my own answer. I feel like this is something to share... At least I myself had this problem for months now, and nobody could help...

I stand by my downvote.  Because your answer doesn't answer your question, rather it solved your original problem.  You didn't understand why you were crashing, so you should have just asked why does this program crash and provided a way to reproduce the crash.  What you actually did was create an XY problem.  You fabricated a secondary requirement (an illogical one at that - asking if a thread can be created is like asking if a file exists - the answer is immediately out of date and therefore not useful.)  Your question is literally "Reliably checking if a thread can be created".  Classic XY.

@Wyck: To be fair, I did ask exactly your suggested question in the first attempt (see link in question) with no result. If you have no idea what's going on, how would you formulate the question?


it is OS-dependent if a thread can be spawned at a given moment, depending on the available RAM and other things. If it's not possible, and we still naively try to do so, the program will crash.

This might technically be true, but in practice, it is not something that anyone worries about, especially on modern desktop computers running Windows (as opposed to tiny embedded systems.)  Millions of programmers all over the planet are writing code every day that spawns threads with reckless abandon and without the slightest worry or concern. If you are the only one encountering issues, then clearly, there must be something wrong with what you are doing.

As others pointed out, the possible number of concurrently running threads is "usually" "very high". I have two different Windows machines, though, [...] for both of which this number is somewhere around <20 for the below (extremely simple!) example.

I do not even need to look at your example below, I can tell you with confidence that the number is nowhere around <20, it is thousands upon thousands, and the problem lies in all certainty in your example below. That is immeasurably more probable than both of your machines being "shitty".
As for the fact that it runs on Linux but not on Windows, this can be fully explained by undefined behavior. If your code triggers undefined behavior, then it may work on one system and not on another, or it might even, by sheer coincidence, work on both systems; it is still wrong.

Now, there is a way to look at the question which is valid: Suppose you are working on a puny, claustrophobic embedded system that does really have a very low limit on the number of threads that it can spawn; how do you know if you can spawn a thread?
The answer here is that if the firmware of the system is written correctly, and if the C++ runtime for that system is written correctly, and if your code is written correctly, then you are not going to get some random crash; instead, it is the constructor of std::thread that will throw an exception.
According to the documentation:

Exceptions
3) std::system_error if the thread could not be started. The exception may represent the error condition std::errc::resource_unavailable_try_again or another implementation-specific error condition.

So, be sure to catch that exception.


So, be sure to catch that exception.
Can you show me how based on my example?


https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try

@Duke - std::system_error if the thread could not be started. The exception may represent the error condition std::errc::resource_unavailable_try_again or another implementation-specific error condition.[ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread]

@Gene: Thank you! I figured it out, though... See my answer...

Suppose you have a function, bool threadCanBeCreated(). And suppose you call it:
if (threadCanBeCreated()) {
    createAThread();
}
else {
    doSomethingElse();
}

Will it be  possible for createAThread() to create a thread? Would it be possible for doSomethingElse() to create a thread?
If the value returned by threadCanBeCreated() could be changed by the action of any other thread in the same program or, by any other process running on the same host, then the answer to both questions is, there is no way of knowing.
After threadCanBeCreated() returns, but before the caller does something about the return value, the answer could change.

Making this a "community" answer because enough other people seem to have said the same thing in comments.

I FINALLY figured it out, and I'm making this an answer since it could help somebody coming across, as desperate as I have been.
3CxEZiVlQ's comment was on the spot:
It looks very strange. Having 48GB and 64GB PCs you run 32-bit applications.
The problem seems to be that I compiled in 32-bit. Changing it to 64-bit I'm able to spawn "as many threads as I like".
(Now, technically this is not an answer to my original question. But I guess for most practical cases this solves all the problems. I still don't know how to catch the exception in the 32-bit case... But being able to spawn a high number of threads made this question far less important. And at least I understand now, why this was only happening to me and to nobody else on earth...)

Thanks to anybody who tried to help! In hindsight I get why I got so many uncomprehending comments and answers. Know that it took me a really long time to figure this out!

This doesn't answer the question you asked, but rather solved the problem you originally had, which is a sign of a poor question -- specifically you asked an XY Problem

@Wyck: You're so right man, I'm sorry! Won't do again...
